# iterator of a set inside a set is equal to the insider set.begin()?

Tags: c++11, stl, set

for example :

```
set<set<T>> outer_set;
set<T> insider_set1, insider_set2;
T a;
insider_set1.insert(a);
outer_set.insert(insider_set1);
outer_set.insert(insider_set2);
set<T>::iterator chosen_itr;
for(auto temp_set: outer_set){
    if(temp_set.count(a)){
        chosen_itr = temp_set.begin();
        break;
    }
}
T b = something(...);
*chosen_itr.insert(b);
```

will this code add b to the insider_set1 inside of outer_set or the chosen_itr belongs to a temporary set that was created at 
    auto temp_set

if chosen_itr is some random iterator how to get the real one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** > iterator of a set inside a set is equal to the insider set.begin()?

no it insider_set1.begin() will point to the first element in the insider_set

to get an iterator (pointer) to the set it self the for(auto set1: outsider_sit) cant be used instead, which i was trying to avoid, is to use

```
 for(auto itr = outsider_set.begin(); ire != outsider_set.end(); ++itr)
```

and then save the itr value at the chosen set.

**2. will this work ?**

no the itr iterator to a set> is an iterator to a constant, sets is immutable in c++ and the values inside a set can not be changed after being add even if those values are containers.

**3. how to add b to a set inside the outsider_set ??**

sense we cant change the values inside the set we have to remove the old    value(insider_set) and insert a new value(insider_set) after being updated  like so:

```
 set<set<T>> outer_set;
 set<T> insider_set1, insider_set2;
 T a;
 insider_set1.insert(a);
 outer_set.insert(insider_set1);
 outer_set.insert(insider_set2);
 set<T> chosen_set;
 set<T>::iterator chosen_itr; // not needed now
 for(auto temp_set: outer_set){
     if(temp_set.count(a)){
         //chosen_itr = temp_set.begin(); // not working 
         chosen_set = temp_set;
         break;
     }
 }
 T b = something(...);
 outsider_set.erase(chosen_set);
 chosen_set.insert(b)
 outsider_set.insert(chosen_set);
```

this solution may not be efficient but I think is the only way, besides using const_cast to insert, if any have better one please mention it.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out in your question, you're keeping a pointer (iterator) into a temporary.  You should use a reference instead:

```
for(auto& temp_set: outer_set){
```

Then the given code would be valid, with one more simple change:

```
chosen_itr->insert(b);
```

Comment: I also had to add typename before set<T>::iterator because of using templates, but chosen_itr->insert(b); is not working am I missing some thing.

Comment: chosen_itr = temp_set.begin(); actually points to the first element in the insider_set1 and not the set itself I cant get to access the set which what I was asking for?